# Counting words in ARRAYS with ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Counting words with Array formula for every cell won't work.

I have tried to use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(SPLIT(Range, " ")))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTA(SPLIT(Range," "))))
```

Both didn't work.

I expected `ARRAYFORMULA` to count words for every cell in the column and put it next to it, but it counted all the text and put it in one cell instead.

Copy of the sheet (Problem in Cell D123): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pPbJ9k4tiLk8hVxHXRgvu6b4vxJOcgTmyFhD_g8gc_Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
 MMULT(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(LEN(A3:A), A3:A, ), " "))<>"", 1, 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(IFERROR(
 QUERY(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(LEN(A3:A), A3:A, ), " "))<>"", 1, 0), "limit 1", 0)))))^0), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

also could be done by just counting the spaces:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "[^\s]", ))+1, ))
```

[image: 0]